# Using collection.deny breaks code

Tags: meteor

Following recommendations from [here](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database), I add a deny clause but now my inserts don't work anymore.

```
todos.deny({
    insert: function (userId, todo) {
        todo['creationDate'] = (new Date()).getTime();
        return false;
    }
})
```

Without the deny, my inserts to todos work. What is going on?

Comment: What other `deny` or `allow` clauses do you have for the `todos` collection?

Comment: I don't have any - this is the only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set up a `Meteor.Collection.deny` clause (assuming you have removed the `autopublish` package), it is important to add at least one `allow` clause - otherwise your server code will never accept any insert.

Add this to your code:

```
todos.allow({
    insert: function (userId, todo) {
        return true;
    }
})
```

You'll probably need to do the same for the `update` and `remove` clauses.